# jsx element type xx does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript in my react app. and when a use a conditional statement to return a Component, I met:
`JSX element type 'XXX' does not have any construct or call signatures`

1. I have make 2 component named A and B.

```js
const A = () => <div>A</div>
const B = () => <div>B</div>
```

2. I'd like to render one of them depend on a condition, so my code like this:

```js
render(){
  const RenderingComponent = someCondition ? A : B  
  return(
    <div>
       <RenderingComponent />
    </div>
  )
}
```

3. VSCode show me the error: `JSX element type 'RenderingComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures`
   PS:
   I know that we can use the most common way to render a condition based component like:

```js
<div>
{condition ? <A/> : <B/> }
</div>
```

I just want to know how to make it works or why should not writing in this style, thanks. :)

Comment: This should work since TS 3.2. What version of TS are you using ?

Comment: Shouldn't `RenderingComponent` return the `<A />` or `<B />` and then use `{RenderingComponent}`.

Comment: @Baruch `RenderingComponent` can conditionally be `A` or `B`, this should work IMO (and I tested it locally and it did work)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir my TypeScript version is 3.4.5.

Comment: @Baruch, In fact, this style of coding can truly rendering as expected, the problem is that VSCode give me this error message.

Comment: @Symous I tested with two components with identical signatures. COuld you provide the definition of A and B. The TS version is correct, does this error appear in vscode ? or during build ?